# Set the system attribute on files exported with Samba

Tags: permissions, samba, file-metadata

I have a Linux server that exports Samba shared folders to a Windows client. From a Linux shell, I need to set the system attribute. On Windows, I would run

```
attrib +s folder
```

How can I do this on the Linux server?

Comment: Do you want to set exactly this in a Windows filesystem, using Linux? Or do you want to set something as-similar-as-possible in a Linux filesystem?

Comment: Using linux I need to set this in a linux filesystem (for samba share - windows clients)

Answer (score 3):

The system attribute is a Windows-specific thing. There's no Linux equivalent.

[Samba has a way to map Windows attributes to permissions that exist on Linux](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch05_03.html). It can be disruptive, however, since the Linux permissions have a different meaning. So the system and hidden attribute are not mapped by default.

To make the system and hidden attributes available, edit the Samba configuration (`/etc/samba/smb.conf` or similar, the exact path depends on your distribution). Turn on the `map system` and `map hidden` options in the `[data]` section:

```
[data]
    …
    map system = yes
    map hidden = yes
```

Then the system attribute is mapped to the group-execute permission bit (`g+x`), and the hidden attribute is mapped to the other-execute permission bit (`o+x`). Thus, the equivalent of `attrib +s some.file` on Windows is

```
chmod g+x some.file
```

on the Linux server.

Beware that this means that if you make a file executable on Linux (`chmod a+x some.file`), this makes it hidden and system on Windows. So make sure that you normally don't make files executable on Linux.

Comment: many thanks for your help! Definitively I need only to make "attrib +s recyclebin" on the virtual recycle bin directory. What's the best way?